# Не запускается JavaFX в Eclipse

Tags: java, javafx

Не помню как устанавливал эту библиотеку в первый раз, но помню что она встала не сразу. В этот раз, уже больше полугода не программирую из-за этого, и никак не могу решить проблему.
[image: Вот так выглядит код, не использую SceneBuilder]

Устанавливал и через Eclipse Marketplace, и вручную, прописывая переменные среды. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и FX не запускается. Может установить ее с нуля? Я пробовал около трех туториалов на полностью чистой от Java ОС, на русском, на английском и даже смотрел видео от индуса, но у меня ничего не получается. Я не понимаю, что упускаю каждый раз.

Comment: Версия java 11 или выше? Вам сюда https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction

Comment: Сделано как написано, даже переменную среду создал вручную. При запуске FX кода:
Error: Unable to initialize main class application.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage